# Combine two windows, where the second window is dependent on first window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The first window is for the number of rectangles. It defines the number of entry boxes in the second window. I want to make a window with the number of rectangles to be entered and when submit button is clicked the content of second window should be appeared below the number of rectangles and submit button so that I can see the number of rectangles entered. Basically, trying to make everything appear in just one window.
Note : The code is verifiable.

```
from tkinter import *

rectangle_values = []
k = 0

def open_window():
    window.withdraw()
    global k
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Rectangles")

    for i in range(0, int(rectangles.get()) * 2):
        if (i % 2) == 0:
            l4 = Label(top, text="Size of rectangle:")
            l4.grid(row=i, column=0)
        en = Entry(top)
        en.grid(row=i, column=1)

    b4 = Button(top, text="Back", width=12, command=lambda: (top.destroy(), window.deiconify()))
    b4.grid(row=int(rectangles.get()) * 2 + 1, column=1)
    k = int(rectangles.get())

window = Tk()

l3 = Label(window, text="Number of Rectangles:")
l3.grid(row=0, column=0)

# defining entries
rectangles = StringVar()
e3 = Entry(window, textvariable=rectangles)
e3.grid(row=0, column=1)

# Defining buttons
b1 = Button(window, text='Submit', width=12, command=open_window)
b1.grid(row=3, column=1)

window.title("Rectangle Configuration")
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place the first 'window' in a frame, and the second in another, then create the second upon validation of the number of rectangles:

**Note:** I added a default value, so that validating and empty entry does not raise an error, and made the second frame reset upon validating a different entry.

```
import tkinter as tk


class NumRectFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Number of Rectangles:")
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.num_rectangles = tk.IntVar()
        self.num_rectangles_entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.num_rectangles)
        self.num_rectangles_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.num_rectangles_entry.insert(tk.END, 0)

        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text='validate', 
                             command=lambda: self.master.get_num_rect(int(self.num_rectangles_entry.get())))
        self.btn.grid(row=1, column=1)


class RectFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, num_rect=0):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.num_rect = num_rect
        for idx in range(self.num_rect * 2):
            if idx % 2 == 0:
                tk.Label(self, text="Size of rectangle:").grid(row=idx, column=0)
            tk.Entry(self).grid(row=idx, column=1)


class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Num Rectangles')
        self.num_rect_fm = NumRectFrame(self)
        self.num_rect_fm.pack()

    def get_num_rect(self, val=0):
        try:
            self.rect_fm.destroy()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        self.rect_fm = RectFrame(self, num_rect=val)
        self.rect_fm.pack()


app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Frame](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm) widget to do it all in one window.

```
from tkinter import *

rectangle_values = []
k = 0

def open_window(rectangles):
    global k
    window.title('Rectangles')
    print(rectangles)
    for i in range(0, int(rectangles) * 2):
        if (i % 2) == 0:
            l4 = Label(frame2, text="Size of rectangle:")
            l4.grid(row=i, column=0)
        en = Entry(frame2)
        en.grid(row=i, column=1)

    frame2.tkraise()

    b4 = Button(frame2, text="Back", width=12, command=lambda: (frame1.tkraise(), window.title('Rectangle Configuration')))
    b4.grid(row=int(rectangles) * 2 + 1, column=1)
    k = int(rectangles)

window = Tk()

frame1 = Frame(window)
frame1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew')
frame2 = Frame(window)
frame2.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew')

frame1.tkraise()

l3 = Label(frame1, text="Number of Rectangles:")
l3.grid(row=0, column=0)

# defining entries
rectangles = StringVar()
e3 = Entry(frame1, textvariable=rectangles)
e3.grid(row=0, column=1)

# Defining buttons
b1 = Button(frame1, text='Submit', width=12, command=lambda: open_window(rectangles.get()))
b1.grid(row=3, column=1)

window.title("Rectangle Configuration")
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry, if my question wasn t clear. But I want the number of rectangles, the submit button, and the sizes of rectangles should appear below them.

Comment: @DevinMaharjan you can still use the Frame widget. Just grid them one below the other, and show _frame2_ afer clicking the Submit button

Comment: Yes, it worked. Can we limit the frame size and just scrollbar?

Comment: @DevinMaharjan To limit frame sizes, have a look at the [https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm] (Grid Manager) (rowspan, columnspan, rowconfigure, columnconfigure, etc). I'm not sure what you need to change with the scrollbar. But, if it is just placement, the grid manager should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Can we put a scrollbar from the whole window together? It would make more sense than just for a frame. Can we do that?

Comment: @DevinMaharjan unfortunately tkinter's root window does not support a scrollbar. But, you can add a canvas to the root window, then add your two frames on top of it (using `create_window` on the canvas). Then, you can make the canvas scrollable.

Comment: Can we put plots using create_window?